# how create new variable form multiple column and row condtion in r

Tags: r, dataframe

How to create new variable in R with matching multiple condition from single data frame. I want create new variable (couple_smokr) from following dataset. Couple related variable is not in dataset and need to create from existing variables (couple will be one who those male and female have similar cluster, houseno and partnernum). If any one have command to create this (couple_smoke) variable, it would be appreciated.

```
View(afgan)
sex    cluster      houseno     partnernum   smoke    **couple_smoke**
male     1            4             2         yes          yes
female   1            4             2         yes          yes
male     1            4             1         no            no
male     3            10            1         no            no
female   3            10            1         yes           no
female   4            4             2          no           no
female   4            4             1          no           no  
male     4            4             3          no           no
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To make your data reproducible, could you dput(head(afgan)) and post the result?

Comment: Why isn't the *male* and *female* in rows 4 and 5 not tagged *yes*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you define `couple_smoke` when a couple lives in the same household and both of them smoke, so that they should also have the same input for the `smoke` variable asides from `cluster`, `houseno`, and `partnernum`. Am I correct?

Then the following should do the trick: first input the data (and please provide dput code next time as csgroen pointed out)

```
afgan <- structure(list(
  sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                  .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
  cluster= c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), 
  houseno= c(4, 4, 4, 10, 10, 4, 4, 4), 
  partnernum= c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3), 
  smoke = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    .Label = c("yes", "no"), class = "factor")),
  .Names = c("sex", "cluster", "houseno", "partnernum", "smoke"), 
  row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then,

```
library(dplyr)
afgan %>% 
  group_by(cluster, houseno, partnernum, smoke) %>% 
  mutate(couple_smoke = ifelse(n() > 1, 1, 0))
```

The `n()` function of `dplyr` package calculates the number of rows in each group.

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: @DharmaN.Bhatta Please consider accepting this as an official answer, if this has helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `ave()` where you pass a vector of 1's equal to `nrow()` of df in order to sum.

```
df$couple_smoke <- ifelse(ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$cluster, df$houseno,
                          df$partnernum, df$smoke, FUN=sum) > 1, 'yes', 'no')
```